# Wordpress show only one post for each author ( Page loads too slow )

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show only one latest post by each author and found this code that it working. However, it takes too long to load the page since I have over 100K authors and 100K posts in database. How can I optimize this code?

```
<?php
  //Displaying latest post per author on front page
  function filter_where($where = '') {
    global $wpdb;

    $where .= " AND wp_posts.id = (select id from {$wpdb->prefix}posts p2 where p2.post_status = 'publish' and p2.post_author = {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_author order by p2.post_date desc limit 0,1)";
    return $where;
  }
  add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
  query_posts($query_string);

//The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

...
  ?>
```

Here is an original article for the code.

http://www.dbuggr.com/smallwei/show-latest-post-author-wordpress-front-page/

Comment: you could try paging through the dataset in blocks of 100

Comment: I'm not very familiar with php. How do I do that?

Comment: this is something for a Google Search, look for tutorials

Comment: If you remove the 'order by' clause, does that speed it up significantly?

Comment: Does not seem to make that much different without order by clause. WHERE clause seems to be the issue but don't know how to make it load faster.

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts`. Secondly, look at transients or the build in cache system to store query results

Comment: @Pieter Thanks for the comment. I'm not very clear about the second part. Could you give me an example of code or something that I can try?